# Stufull column content in MY SQL AND PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

Consider:Table name:Oneline Exam

```
Tablename : exam
Column name:Question1
Column name:OptionA
Column name:OptionB
Column name:OptionC
Column name:OptionD
```

On each Click on page

```
Column name:Question1
Column name:OptionB
Column name:OptionC
Column name:OptionA
Column name:OptionD
```

Option must be stufful and question too.Any one help me plz

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what your problem is and what you have tried.

Comment: The Problem is oneline examination.When two user writing same exam eg:Java.They have same question but question order and answer order must be stufful.sir

Answer (score 0):

shuffle Options Only

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Question,answer,A,B,C,D,sno FROM quest where 
SubjectName='$sub' order by rand()");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
$Question['Question']=$row['Question'];
$answer['answer']=$row['answer'];
$A=$row['A'];
$B=$row['B'];
$C=$row['C'];
$D=$row['D'];
$sno['sno']=$row['sno'];
}   
$options = array($A,$B,$C,$D);
shuffle($options);
```